# How do I print a blank line whenever the first letter of the state differs from the previous state's first letter

Tags: python

I am given a list of states as a `.txt` file. I was able to read each line, stripping off newline character and append data to `states_list`, but I also need to print a blank line whenever the first letter of the current state differs from the previous state's first letter.

Here is what I have tried:

```
states_list = []
n = 0

with open('states.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        state = line.strip('\n')
        states_list.append(state)

for each in states_list:
    if states_list[n][0] != states_list[n+1][0]:
        print("\n")
    print(each)
```

Comment: I don't see a question here...

Comment: The OP signed up today and this is the OPs first post. WHY SO MANY DOWN-VOTES???

Comment: Why downvotes? Because it's a code dump with no actual question. Such "questions" show no research effort and are neither clear nor useful, which describes the criteria for a downvote.

Comment: And the OP clearly did not read "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" before asking his/her question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to compare with other members, don't use the for-each loop.

```
for i in range(len(states_list)):
     if i > 0:
         if states_list[i][0] != states_list[i-1][0]:
             print('\n')
     print(states_list[i])
```

Comment: Using this method, first element won't be printed.

Comment: Good catch, fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of going about this is to use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
with open('states.txt', 'r') as f:
    states = [line.strip('\n') for line in f]

for a, b in zip(states, states[1:]):
    if a[0] != b[0]:
        print("\n")
    print(a)
print(states[-1])
```

In the end, it produces the same result as jeff carey's answer, but perhaps in a more Pythonic/elegant way.

Comment: Thank you! And I learned about zip( ) for the first time, as well!